# How do I fix my input validation loop without breaking the other parts of my code?

Tags: python

Okay, so I am very new to Programming, as in like, 1 month into a course, and I am currently trying to make a code which finds out through user input, if the year is a leap year, and shows the season of the month you were born in. I am trying to make a while loop that will stop the program if the input is 'zzz', but in trying to do so, it cancels everything out. I have a function for the year which works fine, but the rest of the program just doesn't seem to work properly. Everything worked as it should until

```
def is_leap(year):
return year % 400 == 0 or (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0)
```

Everything worked as it should until I made the loop for the 'zzz' part, which is this code:

```
name = input("Enter your name (zzz to stop): ")
while name == 'zzz':
    print("Program Ended")
    break

while name != 'zzz':
   break
```

I think break is supposed to stop it from repeating, which is what it appears to be doing, but I just don't understand why it's causing everything else to fail. This is the whole code:

```
def is_leap(year):
   return year % 400 == 0 or (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0)

name = input("Enter your name (zzz to stop): ")
while name == 'zzz':
    print("Program Ended")
    break

while name != 'zzz':
   break



month = int(input("Please enter a valid month number (1-12): "))
if month in range(1,12):
    while True:
       if month in (1,2,12):
          season = 'winter'
       elif month in (3,4,5):
          season = 'spring'
       elif month in (6, 7, 8):
          season = 'summer'
       elif month in (9, 10, 11):
          season = 'fall'

year = int(input("What is your Birth year? "))
if year in range(1000, 10000):
      if is_leap(year) == 'True':
         print("Hello,", name + "!","You were born in the", season, "and",year,"was a leap year",sep=' ')
         
      else:
         print("Hello,", name + "!","You were born in the", season, "and",year,"was not a leap year",sep = ' ')
else:
   print("Year is invalid.")
```

Some of the individual parts seem to be working, and I'm sure there's just some tiny thing that will fix it, like some indentation, or maybe I'm using part of the code wrong, like the "While True" thing. I'm not sure, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong, and quite frankly I've spent too long on this code, to no avail. The issue is that when I try to find the season, sometimes it says it's undefined which I think is because of the indentation, or it repeats the season, skips whole parts of code entirely, etc. I don't know what's wrong with the code, but if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, since you never update `name` in the loop.

Comment: The IDE, if you use one, is irrelevant to code questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and I`am not sure what do you mean by "causing everything else to fail", but your code had the following issues:

```py
import sys

def is_leap(year):
   return year % 400 == 0 or (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0)

name = input("Enter your name (zzz to stop): ")

# The first loop behaves like an if statement because
# 'break' exits the current loop, not the program
# To stop the program you can use 'sys.exit'
if name == 'zzz':
    sys.exit("Program ended")

# second loop is pointless because it doesn't do anything 

while True:
    month = int(input("Please enter a valid month number (1-12): "))
# The 'in range' check is pointless because it just does what the
# separate checks would do if the month is invalid: nothing
# To prevent the program looping forever we include the input
# in the loop and exit the loop if it was valid
    if month in (1,2,12):
        season = 'winter'
        break
    elif month in (3,4,5):
        season = 'spring'
        break
    elif month in (6, 7, 8):
        season = 'summer'
        break
    elif month in (9, 10, 11):
        season = 'fall'
        break

year = int(input("What is your Birth year? "))
if year in range(1000, 10000):
      # is_leap returns a bool, not a string
      # Furthermore we can remove the equality check because
      # the if statement is doing this already
      if is_leap(year):
         print("Hello,", name + "!","You were born in the", season, "and",year,"was a leap year",sep=' ')
         
      else:
         print("Hello,", name + "!","You were born in the", season, "and",year,"was not a leap year",sep = ' ')
else:
   print("Year is invalid.")
```

You can make your code more readable by using f strings:

```
      if is_leap(year):
         print(f"Hello, {name}! You were born in the {season} and {year} was a leap year")
         
      else:
         print(f"Hello, {name}! You were born in the {season} and {year} was not a leap year")
```

Comment: Is it possible to have it repeat the input for the month without having it exit the program with sys.exit? The issue was it kept on repeating the input statement even when it was within the range. That was the reason why I had the while loop and the range part. So I was trying to make the program repeat "Please enter a valid month number (1-12): ", when it wasn't with inthe range until it received a valid input, in which case it would continue the program.

Comment: Yes, in this case you have to include the input for the month in the loop, remove the else block and execute 'break' after assigning the season.

Comment: Thanks, man! I appreciate your help with this.